# Create .exe file for java application (with jvm)

Tags: java, exe

I'd like to create a single executable file for Windows with the JVM packaged inside of it.
Therefore, the user will be free of installing java and assigning the `JAVA_HOME` system variable. 
I can't find an appropriate guide for this stuff.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to use Launch4J, which is exactly what you need.
Here is a link : http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

It packs a jar into a exe with the JRE inside.